# Missing pixels in charcters when printed on console (C#)

Tags: c#, character, console-application, symbols, missing-data

I have very uncanny problem about **Win32 console**.
There are missing pixels in the console cell like that:

[image]

Okay, let's consider the problem a little bit more detailed. I figure out the bug comes, when all of this **3 factors** are available:

- We must use symbol that we can see the **first column of pixels** is missing, so **'i'** will be useless in our case, because it's printed on middle of the cell, but character like **'0'**, or better **'\u2593'** (which is filling the cell fully) is going to be good choice as well:

  `char myChar = '\u2593';`
- Also need to change the **Console.ForegroundColor** different from our default console color. For example - Yellow:

  `Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Yellow;`
- Finally, print symbols **backward** through moving the cursor position, so we're going to use at least twо times this lines:

  `Console.SetCursorPosition(left, 0);`

  `Console.Write(myChar);`

Now we are ready to simulate our problem with the following code:

```
static void Main()
{
    char myChar = '\u2588';

    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Yellow;

    for (int i = 5; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        Console.SetCursorPosition(i, 0);
        Console.Write(myChar);
        Console.SetCursorPosition(i, 0);
        Console.Write(myChar);
    }

    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

The problem can be observe even more clearly in this console snake game:

[image]
Here's an explanation of the previous one screenshot:

[image]

So, is it possible to get rid of this irritating effect of cracked ASCII, given that I use filling symbols, change the console colors and print backward?

Comment: Your issue is strictly a consequence of the specific command-line interpreter window used, which is not a _programming_ question at all. If you don't want to deal with the artifacts inherent in the specific CLI window, then don't make your program a console program (i.e. use a conventional graphical API) or configure your OS to use a different CLI (if possible).